# Как получить тип при помощи Assembly

Tags: c#, assembly

Я хочу получить не `System.Type`, а непосредственно объект класса `MyClass`. Гуглил, находил пару способов, но в одном надо реализовывать `IConvertible`, а другим (`TypeDescriptor`) не получается воспользоваться. Как сделать?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    Type type = assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "MyClass"); 
    //Теперь надо получить из type объект класса MyClass
}

class MyClass
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: [Activator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спасибо! Проблема решена, то что нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал класс `Activator` следующим образом:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Type type = assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "MyClass");

var result = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```